# how to use third party javascript from ember-cli route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I work on an ember-cli project.
I want to use a javascript library in the route.

It is called CarrotSearchFoamTree.

In order that it will work i added in Brocfile.js

```
app.import('vendor/foamtree/carrotsearch.foamtree.js');
```

When i write in my route

```
 var foamtree = new CarrotSearchFoamTree({
         id: "visualization",
         pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
         initializer: "treemap",
         relaxationVisible: false,
         relaxationQualityThreshold: 5,
         rolloutDuration: 0,
         pullbackDuration: 0,
         finalCompleteDrawMaxDuration: 50,
         finalIncrementalDrawMaxDuration: 20
       });
```

jshint in the build tells me:

> routes/search.js: line 104, col 25, 'CarrotSearchFoamTree' is not defined.

How can i avoid this error?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to the `.jshintrc` configuration like:

```
"predef": {
  "CarrotSearchFoamTree": true
}
```

And you shouldn't see the warning anymore.