# How to use third party npm packages with ember cli app

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

**EDIT:** *this is actually about any npm package which is not designed to play along with ember. In my case, I tried to make crypto-js work, but it seems to be always the same trouble with any npm package not specially designed for ember cli.*

I want to use cryptoJS in my ember app, which I'm currently refactoring with ember cli, but I'm having a lot of trouble importing all the third party packages and libraries I'm already using, like for example cryptoJS.

CryptoJS at least has a package for npm, I don't even want to think about what happens if some of my included libraries don't have a package...

Am I just missing the point in the documentation of ember-cli or is it really not described how to import other npm packages and also how to inlcude non-package libraries properly to keep them under version control and dependency control?

If I follow the description of the crypto-js package manual:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
console.log(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1("Message", "Key"));
```

I get and error in my `ember build`

```
utils/customauthorizer.js: line 1, col 16, 'require' is not defined.
```

Thanks for any help on this, I'm very excited about the ember cli project, but importing my existing ember app has been quite painful so far...

**EDIT:**

Just importing unfortunately does not work.

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

throws during the build

```
daily@dev1:~/VMD$ ember build
version: 0.1.2
Build failed.
File: vmd/utils/customauthorizer.js
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/daily/VMD/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-F7mfDQyP.tmp/crypto-js.js'
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/daily/VMD/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-F7mfDQyP.tmp/crypto-js.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:721:18)
    at addModule (/home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:84:46)
    at addModule (/home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:133:9)
    at addModule (/home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:133:9)
    at /home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-es6-concatenator/index.js:59:7
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (/home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:470:16)
    at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (/home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:482:17)
    at $$$internal$$publish (/home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:453:11)
    at $$rsvp$asap$$flush (/home/daily/VMD/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1531:9)
```

Comment: Ember cli uses es6 modules, to use it you would need to `import CryptoJs from 'crypto-js';`

Comment: yeah ehm, that does not work... I first thought it should work like that too... :( It might be just a wrong path, but is there any way to find out? I updated my answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this. When I look at the tmp folder I can see that broccoli doesn't include my npm packages in the vendor tree. Anything in my bower or vendor directory are however.

Comment: @antony: yes, I noticed the same when I added the third party library to the vendor directory by hand... see my answer below. I still hope someone comes up with a straight forward solution which makes me feel really stupid to not have found it myself ;)

Comment: @antony: I think the "bower-way" like described in my answer below is the way to go... not with npm packages though, but git repositories. As far as I understand it's only good to install npm packages if they are actually made for ember cli

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The easiest and [recommended answer is to use `ember-browserify`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2949#issuecomment-75865249). (as [support for bower packages will be removed in the future.](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2949#issuecomment-85634073))

This is an example for using the npm package `dexie` within an Ember CLI app.

Install browserify: `npm install ember-browserify --save-dev`

Install dexie (or whatever module you need): `npm install dexie --save-dev`

Import the module like this: `import Dexie from 'npm:dexie';`

---

---

**UPDATE (April 2021):**

ember-browserify has now been is deprecated in favor of either [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import) or [ember-cli-cjs-transform](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-cjs-transform)

(see the deprecation [warning at the top of ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify))

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:** I got this to work much better and straight forward! Thanks to the comment of @j_mcnally!

Will leave the first answer down there so everyone can see what trouble I was coming from :)

**What I did:**

`bower install crypto-js=svn+http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/#~3.1.2 --save`

In my file `Brocfile.js` I could just do `app.import('bower_components/crypto-js/build/rollups/hmac-md5.js');`

No manual downloading or moving files, just managing a dependency, much better solution!

But honestly, it was still a lot of vodoo! Until I found the documentation... sweet: http://bower.io/docs/api/#install

---

**OLD approach**

I got this to work, but I can not tell how pretty or correct that approach is. Including third party packages or libraries with ember cli is pretty far away from straight forward or self explaining.

The ressources which led me to my working solution were:

- [how to use third party javascript from ember-cli route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775760/how-to-use-third-party-javascript-from-ember-cli-route)
- https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/757

The following steps I took to get it working:

- I manually downloaded the library https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/downloads/detail?name=CryptoJS%20v3.1.2.zip and unziped it
- I manually created a directory in my vendor directory: `mkdir vendor/crypto-js`
- I appended `app.import('vendor/crypto-js/hmac-md5.js');` to the `Brocfile.js` file
- I added `"CryptoJS"` to the `"predef"` key in the `.jshintrc` file

Then the build worked and I could eventually use the library.

Sadly I didn't get the npm package to work! I had to manually download the zip file, unzip it and move it to the correct location and if the version changes, it's not under any version/dependency control... I will not mark this as an answer, since it does not satisfy me at all, but at least I wanted to share what I did to make it work for me.

Comment: use bower to get the js file rather than including it in vendor manually. vendor should be excluded from git and bower should manage the install.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Sounds much more like what I actually want to do! I'm sure if you make that an generic answer, you would help not only me very much... But I'll go for it myself, just haven't touched bower yet ;)

Comment: NOTE: Adding "CryptoJS" to the "predef" key in the .jshintrc file is still required as of Ember 1.10.0 or else JSHint will present an error in the console.

Answer (score 2):

As Timm describes, using browserify gets the code injected into your ember app.  However, I was having trouble actually using the injected module.  In order to do that I had to actually create the module with `New` before I could use it:

In order to import an NPM module.

1) install browserify:

`npm install ember-browserify --save-dev`

2) install your modele:

`npm install my-module --save-dev`

3) Import your module into your ember file of interest (app/controller/post.js):

`import Module from 'npm:my-module';`

4) use the module from within your code by creating the module with `New`:

`var output = new Module(var1, var2, etc.);`

Answer (score 1):

even though this is an old thread thought I would contribute as I spent a while doing this. The specific package I was trying to link to ember was 'd3plus' and had to do a variety of things to get it to work.

1. `npm install ember-browserify --save-dev`
2. `npm install d3plus --save-dev`
3. `ember install ember-cli-coffeescript`
4. `npm install --save-dev coffeeify coffeescript`

then in your component do
`import d3plus from 'npm:d3plus';`

For a long time I was getting runtime errors when it was searching for the coffescript and figured this would be helpful for people specifically looking for d3plus.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Pablo Morra](https://disqus.com/by/pablomorra/) on a [comment](https://simplabs.com/blog/2017/02/13/npm-libs-in-ember-cli.html#comment-3540696278) of the [simplabs' post "Using npm libraries in Ember CLI"](https://simplabs.com/blog/2017/02/13/npm-libs-in-ember-cli.html), third party npm modules can be imported on Ember.js from version 2.15 **directly without the need of addons or wrappers**:

https://www.emberjs.com/blog/2017/09/01/ember-2-15-released.html#toc_app-import-files-within-node_modules

Unfortunately documentation is still on work and it doesn't say that npm modules can be imported, only bower and vendor ones:

https://github.com/emberjs/guides/issues/2017
https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/

I've gotten 2 solutions to import third party npm modules directly on Ember.js from the [Ember CLI documentation about managing dependencies](https://ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies), although it's also out-of-date and says that npm modules can't be imported, only bower and vendor ones:

### npm module as Standard Anonymous AMD Asset

https://ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies#standard-anonymous-amd-asset

> [AMD: Asynchronous Module Definition](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md)

I prefer and use this way because it avoids global variables and follows the `import` convention of Ember.js.

**ember-cli-build.js:**

```
app.import('node_modules/ic-ajax/dist/amd/main.js', {
  using: [
    { transformation: 'amd', as: 'ic-ajax' }
  ]
});
```

`amd` is the type of transformation applied, and `ic-ajax` is the module name to be used when it's imported on a javascript file.

**on Ember.js javascript file (router, component...):**

```
import raw from 'ic-ajax';
// ...
icAjaxRaw( /* ... */ );
```

`raw` is a module exported by `ic-ajax`.

That's the way it worked for me although the Ember CLI documentation shows the `import` other way that **didn't work for me**, maybe because of the specific package I was importing:

```
import { raw as icAjaxRaw } from 'ic-ajax';
//...
icAjaxRaw( /* ... */ );
```

### npm module as global variable

https://ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies#standard-non-amd-asset

**ember-cli-build.js:**

```
app.import('node_modules/moment/moment.js');
```

**on Ember.js javascript file (router, component...):**

```
/* global moment */
// No import for moment, it's a global called `moment`

// ...
var day = moment('Dec 25, 1995');
```

`/* global moment */` is an annotation for ESLint not to show an error when building the project because `moment()` is not defined in the file.

### npm module as Standard Named AMD Asset

https://ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies#standard-named-amd-asset

Ember CLI also shows a third option that **didn't work for me**, maybe because of the specific package I was importing:

**ember-cli-build.js:**

```
app.import('node_modules/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js');
```

**on Ember.js javascript file (router, component...):**

```
import { raw as icAjaxRaw } from 'ic-ajax';
//...
icAjaxRaw( /* ... */ );
```

### npm module as AMD JavaScript modules

https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_amd-javascript-modules

The way described on Ember.js documentation about Managing Dependencies **didn't work for me** either, maybe because of the specific package I was importing:

**ember-cli-build.js:**

```
app.import('node_modules/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js', {
  exports: {
    'ic-ajax': [
      'default',
      'defineFixture',
      'lookupFixture',
      'raw',
      'request'
    ]
  }
});
```

**on Ember.js javascript file (router, component...):**

```
import { raw as icAjaxRaw } from 'ic-ajax';
//...
icAjaxRaw( /* ... */ );
```