# Initialize cloudinary_js v2 in Ember JS app

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images to cloudinary from an EmberJS app (v2.6), following the [post of Beerlington](http://beerlington.com/blog/2014/07/20/direct-unsigned-cloudinary-uploads-with-emberjs/) where it uses [cloudinary_js](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js) (now with new API v2) and in order to install it :

```
npm install blueimp-file-upload --save
npm install cloudinary-jquery-file-upload --save
```

But when I'm trying to initialize the cloudinary the library is not recognized.

```js
#app/initializers/cloudinary.js
export default {
  name: 'cloudinary',
  initialize: function(/* container, app */) {
    jQuery.cloudinary.config({
      cloud_name: ENV.CLOUDINARY_NAME
    });
  }
};

#console
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

Comment: ember-cli-build.js -  app.import(<path>.js>.... include all the required files.

Comment: as I installed the libraries with npm they are in npm_modules/ and when I tried to import it in ember-cli-build.js, it complains. it works for vendor/ and bower_components/

Comment: I also tried with ember-browserify but it didn't work with cloudinary-jquery-file-upload neither :(

Comment: This will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544578/how-to-use-third-party-npm-packages-with-ember-cli-app  - Is there any specific reason for you to go only with npm packages.

Comment: becouse in the 'cloudinary-jquery-file-upload.js' file that I get installing with npm I found the method 'unsigned_cloudinary_upload' but in the js file get by bower I couldn't find that method.  I already tried with ember-browserify unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ember.js is essentially a client side framework, you need to use bower libraries instead of npm ([more](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_bower)).

Install Cloudinary using bower:

```
bower install cloudinary-jquery-file-upload --save
```

(blueimp will be installed as a dependency.)

Add the imports to your `ember-cli-build.js` file:

```js
/*jshint node:true*/
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });

    app.import("bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js");
    app.import("bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js");
    app.import("bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js");
    app.import("bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js");
    app.import('bower_components/cloudinary-jquery-file-upload/cloudinary-jquery-file-upload.js');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

Add `jQuery` to the global definitions in `.jshintrc` (showing *fragment* here):

```
{
  "predef": [
    "document",
    "window",
    "-Promise",
    "jQuery",
    "$"
  ],
  "browser": true,
  // rest of file...
}
```

Add `cloudinary` too if you intend to use the cloudinary namespace directly.

Now you can use Cloudinary and Blueimp in your code. For example:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend(
  {
    model() {
      $.cloudinary.config({"cloud_name": "your_cloud"});
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".cloudinary-fileupload").cloudinary_fileupload(

        // etc.

        )}
      );
    }
  });
```