# How to include something from NPM with aliasing in your Ember CLI build?

Tags: ember.js, broccolijs

I'm trying to include an NPM package ([this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edzif-validator)), that has a dependency that needs *aliasing* to get the browser version (as [described here](https://github.com/jeffbski/joi-browser#webpack)) in my ember-cli build. In [the official documentation](https://ember-cli.com/asset-compilation), it's not really clear how this can be done.

Ideally, this would be something like this:

```
app.import('joi-browser', { alias: 'joi' });
app.import('edzif-validation');
```

But that does not work. Does anyone have a clue on how to coax the ember-cli/broccoli setup to do this?

Comment: Side Note: app.import is only for bower_components and vendor folder. and also app.import should include path smething like this app.import('bower_components/<path>.js')

Comment: @kumkanillam as stated, the example doesn't work, but if you have some information on how to include npm packages, I'm all ears.

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29544299/5771666) will help. Basically install` ember-browserify` addon and npm install the required module and import using from `npm:modulename`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use third party npm packages with ember cli app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544578/how-to-use-third-party-npm-packages-with-ember-cli-app)

Comment: @locks as far as I can see, the other one doesn't cover the aliasing part.