# Installing third party dependencies in ember v1

Tags: ruby, ember.js, npm, ember-data

I am new to ember.js and am running ember v1 on rails. My goal is to install a third party plugin using `npm` or `bower`.  The plugin is the [leaflet-routing-machine](http://The%20plugin%20that%20I%20would%20like%20to%20install%20is%20the%20leaflet-routing-machine). This question has already been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544578/how-to-use-third-party-npm-packages-with-ember-cli-app) but when I run

```
npm install ember-browserify --save-dev
```

nothing is added to the gemfile.

What would be the equivalent of `gem install` for a third party plugin in Ember v1?

gemfile.lock:

```
ember-data-source (1.0.0.beta.11)
  ember-source
ember-rails (0.15.0)
  active_model_serializers
  barber (>= 0.4.1)
  ember-data-source (>= 1.0.0.beta.5)
  ember-source (>= 1.1.0)
  execjs (>= 1.2)
  handlebars-source (> 1.0.0)
  jquery-rails (>= 1.0.17)
  railties (>= 3.1)
ember-source (1.8.1)
  handlebars-source (~> 1.0)
```

Comment: What would you expect to be added to the Gemfile? The Gemfile is for `Bundler` a ruby "package manager" if you will. `npm` does not care about the Gemfile and `Bundler` can't help for non gemified libraries. These are separate concerns and will to be dealt with independently

Comment: Thanks. How should one go about installing non-gemified libraries ? By building a native extension ?

Comment: I would start by looking at [`npm-rails`](https://github.com/endenwer/npm-rails) seems like it might work well for your scenario

Comment: `embor-browserify` is for `ember-cli`, not for ember v1. Same is true for the question you have linked. Do you understand that you're trying to use an very, very old version of ember?