# Emberjs : how to import after 'npm install'

Tags: ember.js, npm-install

Trying to use howler.js (https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation) in a Controller.

There is no addon for Howler but it exists as a npm package.

I did an `npm install` and subsequently got an update in package.json like this :

`"dependencies": {
    "bootswatch": "^4.0.0",
    "howler": "^2.0.9",
    "npm": "^5.8.0"
  }`

In the controller I added this import

`import {Howl} from 'howler';`

But when I try to execute the code I get a runtime error

`Could not find module 'howler' imported from 'foo/controllers/bar'`

When I do a `find` for `*howl*` this is what I find

`./node_modules/howler/dist/howler.js
./node_modules/howler/dist/howler.core.min.js
./node_modules/howler/dist/howler.min.js
./node_modules/howler/dist/howler.spatial.min.js
./node_modules/howler/src/howler.core.js
./node_modules/howler/src/plugins/howler.spatial.js`

Should my import have a path to these files as part of it ? If so which one ?

Would appreciate some advice about whether there's something obviously wrong in what I've done there.

Emberjs version is 3.0.

Thanks

Comment: I think the package `howl` is not exporting an es6 module! Try to access it via window global variable - `Howl` like in the docs - https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#examples

Comment: @GokulKathirvel : Thanks. Before I read your reply I had decided to try to use ember-browserify which helped but hasn't yet worked . I have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091963/emberjs-ember-browserify-x-is-not-a-constructor?noredirect=1&lq=1 .Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use third party npm packages with ember cli app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544578/how-to-use-third-party-npm-packages-with-ember-cli-app)

Answer (score 3):

You can import the `howler.js` inside your `ember-cli-build.js` like this

```
app.import('node_modules/howler/dist/howler.min.js')
```

Then you can use `Howl` as global variable inside you ember app.

Comment: Thanks. Before I read your reply I had decided to try to use ember-browserify which has raised a different issue. I have created a new question about that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091963/emberjs-ember-browserify-x-is-not-a-constructor?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: In addition to the above, I would recommend also adding a vendor-shim to prevent using `Howl` as a global variable. See [this](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#javascript-assets).