# Emberjs / ember-browserify : "X is not a constructor"?

Tags: ember.js, import, browserify, npm-install

*This question relates to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083444/emberjs-how-to-import-after-npm-install).*

Trying to use howler.js (https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation) in a Controller.

There is no addon for Howler but it exists as a npm package.

I've followed the [instructions to use ember-browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify#synopsis) and then started the ember dev server (`ember s`).

The import looks like this :

`import Howl from "npm:howler";`

I've also tried this :

`import {Howl as Howl} from "npm:howler" ;`

and this :

`import {Howl} from "npm:howler" ;`

In all cases when I attempt to make use of Howler like this :

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ['https://example.com/foo.mp3']
});
sound.play();
```

I get an error in the console (first import shown above) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: _npmHowler.default is not a constructor
```

or (second and third import shown above) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: _npmHowler.Howl is not a constructor
```

The example code for Howler is [here](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#quick-start) and as far as I can see what I'm doing is in line with those examples.

Any suggestions welcome.

---

FWIW: this is the same body of code as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083444/emberjs-how-to-import-after-npm-install) but since that question I've moved onto using [ember-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-browserify)

---

EDIT: This question has been tagged as "possibly a duplicate" of [How to use third party npm packages with ember cli app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544578/how-to-use-third-party-npm-packages-with-ember-cli-app) . On closer examination I think it's clear that is not the case. The cited question does not mention the specific error message that I mention in my question , "...is not a constructor", neither does the OP of that question use ember-browserify, which is an integral part of my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use third party npm packages with ember cli app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544578/how-to-use-third-party-npm-packages-with-ember-cli-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Howler probably exports more than the constructor function, so you need to make sure you are accessing that part of the module:

```
import howler from ‘npm:howler’;

let sound = new howler.Howl(...)
```