# Could Import bpmn-js,bpmn-js-properties-panel module using ember-browserify

Tags: javascript, ember.js, node-modules, bpmn.io, ember-cli-rails

I have **ember-cli 2.16.2**. I am getting the following error when I try to import **bpmn-js** module in one of my route:

> Uncaught Error: Could not find module `npm:bpmn-js` imported from
>   `prject/routes/hello`
>       at missingModule (loader.js:247)
>       at findModule (loader.js:258)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add more code to make this issue replicable.

Comment: Did you spot question [How to use third party npm packages with ember cli app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544578/how-to-use-third-party-npm-packages-with-ember-cli-app)?

Comment: I tried ember-browserify but it throws a build error : 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'source type: module'.

Comment: The import statement should go at the very top of a file. Did you put it inside a function/object?

Comment: Did you place those modules in the dependencies hash of your package.json?

Comment: I have the import statement at the very top below import of ember and It is also saved in package.json.